# Why image not showing while download html to pdf using JavaScript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to generate HTML to pdf in javascript using the html2pdf plugin. The page is working fine if I open the HTML file in the browser but when I generate it to pdf, the image is not rendered in PDF and the date is also not in a proper format in PDF. I am new to this. Anyone, please do help. Thanks in advance

```css
body {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card-0 {
  min-height: 110vh;
  background: linear-gradient(-20deg, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, #f66700 50%);
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  font-weight: 500
}

.container {
  border-radius: 20px
}

.btn {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

select:active {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline-width: 0 !important
}

select:after {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline-width: 0 !important
}

input,
textarea {
  padding: 10px 12px 10px 12px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  resize: none
}

select:focus,
input:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #2196F3 !important;
  outline-width: 0 !important;
  font-weight: 400
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 14px
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #304FFE;
  outline-width: 0
}

button:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline-width: 0
}

.form-control {
  height: calc(2em + .75rem + 3px)
}

.inner-card {}

.card-0 {}

.card-1 {
  border-radius: 17px;
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 15px 0px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important
}

#file {
  border: 2px dashed #92b0b3 !important
}

.color input {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.files:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  content: attr(data-before);
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center
}

#file {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 95px 0 0 100%;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/VXWKoBD.png') top center no-repeat #fff;
  background-size: 55px 55px
}

#Gstbtndiv {
  padding: 20px;
}

table td {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  text-align: center;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding-top: 08px;
  padding-bottom: 08px;
}

table thead {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f66700;
}

#AddBtn {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.inptfield {
  border-color: #f66700;
}

#cardstyle {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

table tr input {
  text-align: center;
}

#Exportid {
  background-color: #f66700;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-color: #f66700;
}

#ExportDiv {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 1px;
}

table tbody tr:first-child i {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.1/html2pdf.bundle.min.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\sylaja\Documents\Dttemplate\dttemplate.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="printThis.js"></script>
  <script>
    function generate() {
      var dateelement = document.getElementById('cardstyle');
      html2pdf(dateelement);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cardstyle">
        <div class="row justify-content-center round">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12 ">
                <div class="card shadow-lg card-1">
                    <div class="card-body inner-card" >
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                                <h3 class="font-weight-bold ml-md-0 mx-auto text-center text-sm-left"style="padding: 10px;text-decoration: underline;" id="invoicehead"> INVOICE</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 sm-order-2">
                                <div class="form-group mb-2" id="invoicenumberdiv">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InvoiceNumber" placeholder="Invoice Number">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-2" id="invoicedatediv">
                                        <input type="Date" class="form-control" id="InvoiceDate">
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 sm-order-1" style="text-align:right;">
                                <img src="digitallogo.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <div id="ExportDiv">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" class="exptopdf" id="Exportid" onclick="generate();">Export to PDF</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[I need to load my company logo in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSj1x.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. When posting a question with code it is better to cut down the code to the smallest demo that illustrates the issue. You might want to edit your question. You should also list what searches you did elsewhere and what you tried already. SO is a site where people will help you but they tend to want you to have done some research first.

Answer (score 0):

For the date format, I don't think there's a solution other than just making a text input where you write the date as the format you want.
For the background issue, try changing where you're assigning the brackground image, like this:

```
    .container { /* don't set the background image here, you're not rendering this*/
        background:transparent;
    }
    #cardstyle { /* use it here. you're rendering from this div on */
        background:linear-gradient(-20deg, rgb(204, 204, 204) 50%, #f66700 50%)
    }
```